# react Multiple images and documents store and fetch URL from Firebase is not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addCriminalData = this.addCriminalData.bind(this);
    this.storeDocumentAndgetUrl = this.storeDocumentAndgetUrl.bind(this);
    this.storeForensicDocumentAndgetUrl = this.storeForensicDocumentAndgetUrl.bind(
      this
    );
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      imgFile: [],
      imgUrl: [],
      docFile: [],
      docUrl: [],
      docForensicFile: [],
      docForensicUrl: [],
    };
  }
  
  upload = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.storeForensicDocumentAndgetUrl(this.storeDocumentAndgetUrl);
  };
  storeImageAndgetUrl = (addCriminalData) => {
    const storage = fire.storage();
    const reference = storage.ref();
    this.state.imgFile.forEach((file) => {
      reference
        .child(file.name)
        .put(file)
        .then(
          (snapShot) => {
            snapShot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
              this.setState(
                (prevState) => ({
                  imgUrl: [...prevState.imgUrl, url],
                }),
                () => addCriminalData()
              );
            });
          },

          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        );
    });
  };
  storeDocumentAndgetUrl = (storeImageAndgetUrl) => {
    const storage = fire.storage();
    const reference = storage.ref();
    this.state.docFile.forEach((file) => {
      reference
        .child(file.name)
        .put(file)
        .then(
          (snapShot) => {
            snapShot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
              this.setState(
                (prevState) => ({
                  docUrl: [...prevState.docUrl, url],
                }),
                () => storeImageAndgetUrl(this.addCriminalData)
              );
            });
          },

          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        );
    });
  };
  storeForensicDocumentAndgetUrl = (storeDocumentAndgetUrl) => {
    const storage = fire.storage();
    const reference = storage.ref();
    let refer = [];
    this.state.docForensicFile.forEach((file) => {
      reference
        .child(file.name)
        .put(file)
        .then(
          (snapShot) => {
            snapShot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
              refer.push(url);
            });
            this.setState({ docForensicUrl: refer }, () => {
              storeDocumentAndgetUrl(this.storeImageAndgetUrl);
            });
          },

          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        );
    });
  };

  setImage = (e) => {
    if (Array.from(e.target.files).length <= 4) {
      const img = Array.from(e.target.files);
      this.setState({ imgFile: img });
    } else {
      alert("You can select maximum 5 Images");
    }
  };
  setDocument = (e) => {
    if (Array.from(e.target.files).length <= 4) {
      const doc = Array.from(e.target.files);
      this.setState({ docFile: doc });
    } else {
      alert("You can select maximum 5 Documents");
    }
  };
  setForensicDocument = (e) => {
    if (Array.from(e.target.files).length <= 4) {
      const doc = Array.from(e.target.files);
      this.setState({ docForensicFile: doc });
    } else {
      alert("You can select maximum 5 Documents");
    }
  };
  addCriminalData = () => {
    console.log(this.state.pic);

    const db = fire.firestore();

    let sgn = this.state.selectedGangName;
    console.log(sgn);
    const userRef = db.collection("students").add({
      name: this.state.username,
      pic: this.state.imgUrl,
      docUrl: this.state.docUrl,
      docForensicUrl: this.state.docForensicUrl,
    });
  };
  handleChangeUsername = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.upload}>
          <label>Username:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.username}
            name="username"
            onChange={this.handleChangeUsername}
          />
          <input
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            onChange={this.setImage}
            multiple
          />
          <input
            type="file"
            onChange={this.setDocument}
            label="Upload Accused mobile details in file/PDF format "
            accept="image/*,application/pdf"
            onKeyPress={(e) => {
              e.key === "Enter" && e.preventDefault();
            }}
            multiple
          />
          <input
            type="file"
            onChange={this.setForensicDocument}
            label="Upload Accused mobile details in file/PDF format "
            accept="image/*,application/pdf"
            onKeyPress={(e) => {
              e.key === "Enter" && e.preventDefault();
            }}
            multiple
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here, In the above code, I have one text input box and two file input boxes and all of those fields are multiples. And i have made call back functions such that first documents and images will upload and get URL, and then that URL along with text input will be stored to firestore. On click of submit button it goes to upload function, then from there it goes to 'storeForensicDocumentAndgetUrl' method, and then 'storeDocumentAndGetUrl' method and then 'storeImageAndGetUrl' method and after getting all URLs it will call 'addCriminalData' method. The callback functions are working correctly, but its storing multiple documents for one time with not proper URL array length with respect to files i have provided.[image: Here, as in this picture, I have given uploaded username, and two files for each file input. But on click of submit button it made multiple documents with not proper URL array length with respect to files i have provided]

Comment: You were faced with a similar problem in [React firebase multiple images select on submit storing only one image URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62848171/react-firebase-multiple-images-select-on-submit-storing-only-one-image-url-in-ar). Did the solution proposed there not work out for you?

Comment: No Sir, it didn't work for me.

Comment: did you get an answer?